# How to get all versions of Confluence page via REST API

Tags: json, api, rest, confluence

I would like to retrieve all versions of a page in Confluence. There is a call in the REST API that claims to return the history, but I have little luck with it.

```
/rest/api/content/{id}/history
```

When I call this I get a response along these lines:

```
{"latest": true,
    "createdBy": {
    "type": "known",
    "profilePicture": {
        "path": "/confluence/s/en_GB/.../profilepics/Avatar-14.png",
        "width": 48,
        "height": 48,
        "isDefault": false
    },
    "username": "first.last@abc123.com",
    "displayName": "First Last",
    "userKey": "userKey"
}, "createdDate": "2014-12-29T13:56:16.000+0100", "_links": {
    "base": "https://host.abc123.net/confluence",
    "context": "/confluence",
    "self": "host.abc123.net/confluence/rest/api/content/12345678/history"
}, "_expandable": {
    "lastUpdated": ""
}}
```

I know that this page has 17 versions in the history through the browser interface. I can't seem to get anywhere by adding any kind of expand= to the query either.

The documentation for Confluence REST API tells me that this call should:

> Returns a full JSON representation of the content's history

If I turn to the "normal" REST API call to retrieve content, I can get some hint about the history in the version structure:

```
{"version": {
    "by": {
        "type": "known",
        "profilePicture": {
            "path": "/confluence/s/en_GB/5639/.../profilepics/default.png",
            "width": 48,
            "height": 48,
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "username": "some.other@abc123",
        "displayName": "Some Other",
        "userKey": "userKeyGuidThingy"
    },
    "when": "2015-01-30T16:00:09.000+0100",
    "message": "",
    "number": 17,
    "minorEdit": false
}      }
```

I am very keen on retrieving the other versions, numbers 1 - 16, but I can't see how..

I'd be most grateful for any help to get me unstuck.. :)

Comment: it seems this is curently not possible. I just upvoted this [improvement request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRA-449) at Atlassian's JIRA. You can upvote it too to attract attention.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example:
Request:
http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version?expand=content

Response:

```
    {
"results": [
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:56:29.000+03:00",
"message": "more stuff",
"number": 6,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "current",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/display/S1/cla1",
"tinyui": "/x/AI15",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "/rest/api/space/S1",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/6"
}
},
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:56:12.000+03:00",
"message": "stuff",
"number": 5,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "historical",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7965962",
"tinyui": "/x/Co15",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952?status=historical&version=5"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child?parentVersion=5",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/5"
}
},
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:39:28.000+03:00",
"message": "",
"number": 4,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "historical",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7965961",
"tinyui": "/x/CY15",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952?status=historical&version=4"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child?parentVersion=4",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/4"
}
},
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:39:12.000+03:00",
"message": "",
"number": 3,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "historical",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7965959",
"tinyui": "/x/B415",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952?status=historical&version=3"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child?parentVersion=3",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/3"
}
},
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:38:36.000+03:00",
"message": "",
"number": 2,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "historical",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7965957",
"tinyui": "/x/BY15",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952?status=historical&version=2"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child?parentVersion=2",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/2"
}
},
{
"by": {
"type": "known",
"username": "admin",
"userKey": "40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000",
"profilePicture": {
"path": "/download/attachments/327681/user-avatar",
"width": 48,
"height": 48,
"isDefault": false
},
"displayName": "admin",
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/user?key=40288ac65c33f555015c33fd0aed0000"
}
},
"when": "2017-10-16T14:23:14.000+03:00",
"message": "",
"number": 1,
"minorEdit": false,
"hidden": false,
"content": {
"id": "7965952",
"type": "page",
"status": "historical",
"title": "cla1",
"extensions": {
"position": "none"
},
"_links": {
"webui": "/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7965955",
"tinyui": "/x/A415",
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/7965952?status=historical&version=1"
},
"_expandable": {
"container": "",
"metadata": "",
"operations": "",
"children": "/rest/api/content/7965952/child?parentVersion=1",
"history": "/rest/api/content/7965952/history",
"ancestors": "",
"body": "",
"version": "",
"descendants": "/rest/api/content/7965952/descendant",
"space": "/rest/api/space/S1"
}
},
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version/1"
}
}
],
"start": 0,
"limit": 100,
"size": 6,
"_links": {
"self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/experimental/content/7965952/version?expand=content",
"base": "http://localhost:8090",
"context": ""
}
}
```

this will get you all versions of a page with version messages

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to get version number.

so If you go to https://confluence.yourdomain.com/rest/api/content/page_id(1234567)/history. You will get the following json response.

```
{
   "previousVersion":{
      "by":{
         "type":"known",
         "profilePicture":{
            "path":"image/path",
            "width":48,
            "height":48,
            "isDefault":true
         },
         "username":"username",
         "displayName":"password",
         "userKey":"userkey"
      },
      "when":"date-time",
      "message":"",
      "number":1,
      "minorEdit":false
   },
   "lastUpdated":{
      "by":{
         "type":"known",
         "profilePicture":{
            "path":"image/path",
            "width":48,
            "height":48,
            "isDefault":true
         },
         "username":"username",
         "displayName":"password",
         "userKey":"userkey"
      },
      "when":"date-time",
      "message":"",
      "number":2,
      "minorEdit":false
   },
   "latest":true,
   "createdBy":{
      "type":"known",
      "profilePicture":{
         "path":"image/path",
         "width":48,
         "height":48,
         "isDefault":true
      },
      "username":"username",
      "displayName":"password",
      "userKey":"userkey"
   },
   "createdDate":"userkey",
   "_links":{
      "base":"https://confluence.yourdomain.com",
      "context":"",
      "self":"https://confluence.yourdomain.com/rest/api/content/page_id/history"
   }
}
```

From that response json just fetch the version number depends on the scripting language that you are using. For Python following the piece of code will fetch the version number.

```
version=requests.get(https://confluence.yourdomain.com/rest/api/content/page_id(1234567)/history)
version= version.json()
print version['lastUpdated']['number']
```

This will give you latest version number of the page.

Comment: the answer only gets the last & the previous , meaning if you have 3 and above you won't get a full response :(